# Binary has a problem: Error: Module did not self-register

Tags: angular, npm, node-sass

- 

> Binary saved to
> node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node Caching binary
> to npm-cache\node-sass\4.7.2\win32-x64-57_binding.node node-sass@4.7.2
> postinstall node_modules\node-sass node scripts/build.js Binary found
> at node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node Testing
> binary Binary has a problem: Error: Module did not self-register. at
> Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:672:18) at Module.load
> (module.js:556:32) at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12) at
> Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3) at Module.require
> (module.js:587:17) at require (internal/module.js:11:18) at
> module.exports (node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:19:10) at
> Object. (node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35) at Module._compile
> (module.js:643:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
> Building the binary locally

- 

Please help

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens mostly because you copied/cloned the repository from somewhere else, but some modules for NodeJS should be installed/registered locally on your machine, during which the happens the build process
So as a solution upgrade the NPM using

```
npm install npm -g
```

after that, delete the node_modules folder, then,

```
npm install
```